# What is the time complexity problem I need to manage on a Hackerank "Ransom Note" - my code runs perfectly

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, complexity

I am trying to solve the ["Ransom Note" problem on hackerank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps).
Why isn't my code getting submitted?
What can I do differently?
is my total time complexity, in this case, it is O(n^2)?

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the checkMagazine function below.
def checkMagazine(magazine, note):
    
    for word in note:                                         # O(n)
        if word not in magazine:                              # O(n)
            return 'No'
        else:
            magazine.remove(word)                             # O(n)

    return 'Yes'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mn = input().split()

    m = int(mn[0])

    n = int(mn[1])

    magazine = input().rstrip().split()

    note = input().rstrip().split()

    print(checkMagazine(magazine, note))
```

Comment: "Why isn't my code getting submitted?" - I guess because you're not submitting it?

Comment: And if you do submit it, it doesn't get accepted. Probably that's what you meant? Then you know that it's not correct, making this off-topic here.

Comment: In your assessment of asymptotic bounds of complexity, you need more variables to model problem size.

Comment: (You may try and find an approach minimising memory required.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some ideas in the discussions tab of the original question:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-ransom-note/forum?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps.

To answer your quesitons: yes, your solution has time complexity of O(n^2).

The optinal solution should have time complexity of O(n):

1. Go through magazine in O(n), get a map from words to counts.
2. Go through note in O(n), also get a map from words to counts.
3. Go through the map in step 2 in O(n), check for each word, whether the count of the map in step 1 is larger or not. Return True only when all the counts are no larger.